# How do I make the initially-selected first segment of a Segmented Picker respond?

Tags: swiftui, uisegmentedcontrol, picker

**Scenario:** The typical Segment with varying number of members, depending on context.

**Problem/Question:** How do I make the *initial segment* ('Countries') respond for the user versus having to select another and return to the first segment that is now responsible?

The Picker apparently doesn't recognize the initial selection; until I chose another member that is not in focus.

[image]

'Countries' visually reacts to touch but doesn't launch a response until the focus is returned to it, after user selects 'SubRegions'.

Isn't there a boolean button-property that handles this?